# How to get specific values on an xml using php?

Tags: php, xml

I'm creating a simple web app using html and php, this app reads an XML file provided by a user on a webpage and then prints some values content on it.

The files are sent to the server by POST and then are read by a php script.

This is a fragment of my xml test file:

```
<cfdi:Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="72.07">
    <cfdi:Traslados>
        <cfdi:Traslado importe="50.00" impuesto="IEPS" tasa="16.00"/>
        <cfdi:Traslado importe="22.07" impuesto="IVA" tasa="16.00"/>
    </cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
```

And this is my code made on php:

```
<?php

foreach ($_FILES['archivos']['name'] as $f => $name) {
$tempPath = $_FILES["archivos"]["tmp_name"][$f];

//Load xml file directly on the temp path
$xml        = simplexml_load_file($tempPath, null, true);
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();

//Creating and loading DOM object
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$dom->load($tempPath);

//Getting IVAs' values
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Impuestos//cfdi:Traslados//cfdi:Traslado') as $impuestos){
    $IVA = $impuestos['importe'];
    echo("IVA = ".$IVA."<br>");
}
}
?>
```

That prints:

IVA = 50.00
IVA = 22.07

[Print's screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMWgD.jpg)

On this case I want to print only the IVA's value but it takes the IEPS' value too because IEPS is on the same path as IVA. These values are only on this part of the file and I don't know if there's a way to separate them.

I just want to select only the IVA's value. Would you help me please?:(

The complete XML file is: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_4w5smeUBJr4cSuQb4CdrQUDhuzuWvMa/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check the value of `$impuestos['impuesto']` with an if!

Comment: It would work only on specific cases, what I need is to check if the value corresponds to IVA and not to other concepts.

Comment: So in other words `if($impuestos['impuesto']==="IVA")`?

Comment: What a dumb, you're right. This is my first time using php, I apologize. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("//cfdi:Comprobante//cfdi:Impuestos//cfdi:Traslados//cfdi:Traslado[@impuesto='IVA']") as $impuestos){
```